# Почему я получаю два процесса при запуске одного файла?

Tags: python, процесс, psutil

Я пытаюсь получить PID процесса исполняемого в файле, но получаю два разных процесса и два разных PID. Мой процессор содержит два ядра и я предполагаю, что скрипт питона выполняется на двух ядрах одновременно и из-за этого получаю два разных PID. Подскажите пожалуйста на какой PID следует обратить внимание?
Код:

```
import psutil
from sys import argv
from datetime import timedelta
import time

NAME = argv[0]

def process_info():
    it = psutil.process_iter(("name", "cmdline", "pid", ))
    for proc in it:
        if "python" in proc.info["name"] and (cl := proc.info["cmdline"]) is not None and len(cl) > 0 and NAME in cl[-1]:
            info = f"PID: {proc.info['pid']}"
            print(info )
process_info()
```

Результат:

```
PID: 3872
PID: 4108
```

Comment: Ядра процессора тут совершенно не причем. Но процесса видимо 2 или у вас еще что то запущено. лучше всего поставьте в конце программы time.sleep(60) и пока она минуту будет ждать и ничего не делать посмотрите обычным ps что у вас в системе с подходящими названиями запущено

Comment: Да и pid идущие с такой большой разницей подсказывают, что тут два процесса, запущенные несколько в разное время

Comment: Напечатайте всю инфу об этих процессах, не только `PID`, может понятнее что-то станет.

Comment: @Mike обратил внимание, что при выполнении кода в окне пайчарма выводится информация об исполняемых файлах и их как раз два, а последний, тот, PID процесса которого я хочу получить: C:\Users\UserName\PycharmProjects\testtest\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/UserName/PycharmProjects/testtest/asdfg.py

Comment: Ну pid текущего процесса и так известен  os.getpid() его дает